# Is there any way I can check how many flush points in a gzip file?

Tags: gzip

I have a huge `.gz` file created from zlib and I want to examine how many flushes points are in it (see http://www.zlib.net/manual.html for gz flush operation). Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [infgen](https://github.com/madler/infgen) to disassemble the stream, and search for empty stored blocks (a line containing only "stored" immediately followed by a line containing only "end").